# HTML mail results in "no contents" on Apple mobile-devices

Tags: php, ios

I'm sending a HTML-mail via PHP-mail(). The contents are some div-containers and a few external images.

On Apple mobile-devices like iPhone and iPad, the mail contents can't be read, instead there is a message "This message has no content". 
The funny thing is, in the preview-pane of the mail-app I can see the first few words of the mail. So the contents are there, at least in some way.
Everything is fine when reading the same mail in Google webmailer.

Can you help?

Edit: As requested, here's the source. $mail has the HTML-mailbody as value.

```
    $id = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $header= "From: Mailer <info@domain.com>\n";
    $header.= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".$id."\n";
    $header.= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format\n";
    $header.= "--".$id."\n";
    $header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $header.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    $header.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
    $header.= $mail."\n";
    $header.= "--".$id."--";

    $betreff = mb_encode_mimeheader("subject", "UTF-8");

    mail($mailaddress, $betreff, $mail, $header);
```

Comment: Sounds like a badly formed [`multipart/alternative`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Alternative) message to me, but you will have to show your code before we can help. You should be using a library like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) for this, it will construct well formed messages and send them correctly for you and you won't get problems like this.

Comment: @dave I'm a bit against libraries because they're like a black-box: They're working fine, but most of us don't know how. So I would like to write my own code and know what I've done wrong. I added the source-code, perhaps you can see the issue.

Comment: Well one issue that immediately strikes me is that you should be using CRLF `\r\n` for line separations, not just LF `\n`. Also you have passed the data `$mail` twice, because you have sent it in the headers and in the body when you pass it to `mail()`. I also see many people passing the body in the headers, but it doesn't seem to make any sense to me. I would put the first two lines (CRLF separated) in the headers, then the rest (also CRLF separated) in the body. I would also move the `MIME-Version: 1.0` to the headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an empty line before your content. In the example above it should be:

"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n"

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue I've been working on.  In my case, the issue was the ORDER of the views.  Mine was a bit different from yours, having "text/html" and "text/plain".

If the "text/html" view was added to the message first, the message would be visible in the preview pane but not the main email pane, and the "text/plain" portion would be visible in the main email pane (but since the test emails had no plain text portion, we were getting the no content message).  Swapping the "text/plain" and "text/html" portions of the message, so the HTML was added to the message after the plain text portion, and the HTML portion of the email became readable in the IOS mail app.